# How to implement a Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.IWizard which copies files from the template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automation, project-template

I created a visual studio multi project template and would like to add an extra folder for an assembly library to the output parent project which is *not* a child project itself.  The final project should look like this.

```
Parent Project
    - Child Project 1
    - Child Project 2
    - Child Project 3
    - lib (not a project, just assemblies)
```

The `lib` directory is currently included in my zipped project template, I would like to copy it from there into the newly created project.  So the question is,

1. What method of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.IWizard` do I need to implement
2. How do I get a reference to the lib directory inside the zipped project template (preferably as a stream of some kind so I do not have to unzip anything myself)
3. How do I get a reference to the newly created parent project directory

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link and download the multi-project template sample.

[Multi-Project Template](http://vsix.codeplex.com/)